# Android ListView or GridView item in xml without adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I want to make a ListView and have my values be static. I think I do not need an adapter. Do I need an adapter?

```xml
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have but then you will need to add ypur own static data for it.

Comment: how i can add own static data in xml

Comment: You hv got textview inside your gridview or listview it seems. So you will have to create those mulitple textviews for each item to be shown as on the listview.

Comment: Thats why we use adapters!